# Was the term connoisseur used during the 1400s?

Tags: 15th-century

I need to know if the title *connoisseur* was used in the 1400's. Connoisseur meaning an expert in art who could judge such art.

I tried some research but didn't seem to be able to find anything

Comment: It would appear to have [originated in the 18th Century](https://www.etymonline.com/word/connoisseur)

Comment: I tried some research but didn't seem to be able to find anything.

Comment: Good example of a question where the key is knowing the research technique. It isn't obvious, but Steve Bird nailed it; the key is to search for the etymology of the term, which will generally indicate the first use of the term.

Comment: FWIW, I don't think this is necessarily off-topic here. However, the English . SE site tends to be a good place for word history questions, due to the high number of users there with access to a copy of the OED.

Comment: @SteveBird Since indeed OED agrees to 1714…

Answer (score -1):

The [OED (1928) Vol. II](https://archive.org/details/in.ernet.dli.2015.271839/page/n843/mode/2up) attests the word only since 1732 or 1714 depending on sense:

> **1.** One who knows, one versed in a subject. *Obs.* **1732 BERKELEY** *Alciphr[on, or the Minute Philosopher]* v. § 27 Commendation of Honour and Good-nature: but the former of these, by *Connoisseurs*, is always understood to mean nothing but Fashion. ....

> **2.** *spec.* A person well acquainted with one of the fine arts, and competent to pass judgement in relation thereto; a critical judge of art or of matters of taste.  **1714 MANDEVILLE** *Fable of Bees (1723) 374 There are Parties among connoisseurs, and few of them agree in their esteem. ....

[image]